# Html validation issue for facebook sharing on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, rwd-theme, facebook

Checking product page html validation I realized we have html validation error for
facebook share button on product page. The error is

> "`Bad value for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in
>   query: [ is not allowed`"

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Atually url for sharing in href attribute is not make correctly.

Causes: May be jquery conflict. check in browser console.

Comment: In product page going to the console I see no js error  and  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[url]=..... is the link that has validation issue